# Android emulator crash on launch

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I'm new to Android development but I have some experience with html,css,php,java,processing.(no experience with console)

I installed all packages and emulator and started doing the developer training build your first app ( http://developer.android.com/training/index.html ). Everything was working fine, but suddenly the emulator is crashing every time I run an application.

I did not change anything AVD-related I just typed some more code following the tutorial and it crashes every time from now on, I also tried creating a new Application and running that one but it resulted in the same crash.

This is the error I am getting after launch:

```
Last login: Mon Sep 15 18:11:37 on ttys001

Macbook-PJ:~ Pieter-Jan$ /Users/Pieter-Jan/Documents/ANDROID/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/tools/emulator64-arm ; exit;


emulator: ERROR: You did not specify a virtual device name, and the system
directory could not be found.

If you are an Android SDK user, please use '@<name>' or '-avd <name>'
to start a given virtual device (see -help-avd for details).

Otherwise, follow the instructions in -help-disk-images to start the emulator

logout

[Process completed]
```

I have no idea what to do with this error-information.. I tried searching the internet and thought I would find an easy explanation but it has been a disappointing search.. one person said type ./emulator -help-disk-images, then you would know how to fix it. (as the error says) But I have no idea where to put this.

- If I launch the project i was working on it crashes.
- If I start a new application (hello world) it crashes.

I already tried making other devices without any success..
It does work on a running android device.

I'm unable to include any printscreens since I've only just created an account.

I'm using OS X 10.9.3

UPDATE:
I did a reinstall fixing the issue.. but now 1 day later the problem re-occurred.. It was working fine for about 7 hours and now none of my apps want to run as the emulator just insta crashes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to configure Android Emulator once SDK is installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15992631/how-to-configure-android-emulator-once-sdk-is-installed)